# Если на сайте часто удаляются, добавляются URL страницы

Tags: seo

Есть сайт , на сайте часто удаляются, добавляются большое количество URL страниц, приблизительно 100000 страниц в месяц. 
    "Время жизни" страницы URL =1 месяц. Вопрос как будет воспринимать Гугл поисковик большой количество отсутствие URL страниц после удаления по истечению месяца, как это влияет в целом на оценку сайта и индексацию ??? Нужно ли какие то дополнительный настройки чтобы поисковик считал это нормой , частое обновление и отсутствие страниц.???

Answer (score 0):

О новых страниах сайта вы сообщаете Гугл с sitemap. После сканирования этих страниц они помещаются в индекс Гугл - база данных. Если вы через месяц удалите эти урлы из сети и из вашего sitemap, то Гугл генерирует ошибки 404 и эти ошибки будут указаны в вашей коноли поиска. Гугл говорит, что такие ошибки 404 не влияют на посковый ранг. Если таких ошибок будет по 100 000 каждый месяц то, возможно, это будет характеризовать веб-сайт как проблемный. И что вы будете делать с таким количеством ошибок в вашей консоли поиска?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, у вас есть некоторые страницы, которые постоянно статичны. Вы можете оставить в индексе только их, а те, время жизни которых около месяца - закрывать от индексации. Почему закрывать? Потому что за месяц вряд ли они принесут вам трафик. Однако, если трафик все таки идет, то при удалении страницы с нее можно делать 301-редирект на "статичную" страницу.